# How to find words that have no characters of an string?

Tags: string, python-2.7, character-arrays

my question is related to python. I have a .txt file that contains some text. I want to have a code that prompts the user to enter a string of forbidden letters and then print the number of words in the file that don’t contain any of them. I wrote this one:

```
letters=raw_input("Please enter forbidden letters")
text=open("p.txt", "r").read().split()
for word in text:
   for i in letters:
       if not j in word:
          print word
```

and also have this one:

```
letters=raw_input("Please enter forbidden letters")
text=open("p.txt", "r").read().split()
for word in text:
   for i in letters:
       for j in i:
           if not j in word:
               print word
```

But both codes give me words that don't contain each of characters and not all characters. for example if my file have "Hello good friends" and user entered "oh", this codes print:

Hello
good
friends
friends

But I expect just "friends" that don't have nor "o" not "h". and expect to have "friends" one time and not two times.
How can I fix my problem?

Comment: You need to store the `word`s you've already `print`ed and make sure you don't `print` them again.

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: @Stack Over Hello problem solved

Comment: oops. @jonrsharpe problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in a set to remove dupes. Then for each word you want to print it only if *all* letters do not appear in the word. Something like this:

```
letters = raw_input("Please enter forbidden letters")
words = set(open("p.txt", "r").read().split())
for word in words:
  if all(letter not in word for letter in letters):
    print word
```

Comment: Thank you so much. its working. even it prints word from the last to the first.

Comment: The order is not deterministic, it depends on the order of the set. You might want to use sorted to sort them lexicographically or using an ordered set of some sort to sort by entry order.